# SQLAlchemy: How to represent data in Python differently than in the database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

In a (postgres) SQLAlchemy model/class, I have several columns that are 'price' columns. I have read that using numeric/money/float types for this sort of data is not a good idea, so I'm storing as INTs (pennies).

I have created validators for these columns that will multiply the input value by 100 and cast to an INT upon insert and update, so that is taken care of.

How do I do the reverse? When I select this data, I want to cast these values to a float and then divide by 100. I cannot seem to find an appropriate sqlalchemy event listener to do this. Is there a correct way of doing this?

PS. As bonus points I might also want to cast to string and add a '$' prefix, so this solution would be very useful to me.

Comment: Float is bad, but what's wrong with decimal/numeric?

Comment: I think due to the dollar value nature of the data, rounding errors are unacceptable, so pennies / ints are used. It was highly recommended by another dev working on the project, so that's what we went with.

Comment: Rounding characteristics of the decimal type is exactly the same as integer, except that it can also handle fractions of a penny. Regardless, if you want to work in pennies, then you're basically losing whatever benefit you had in dealing with pennies if you then convert it to a float in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using validators for this.  Instead, I'd recommend using TypeDecorator; see  [this discussion](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html) within the SQLAlchemy documentation.  You'll create a TypeDecorator for a Price type that multiplies by 100 on bind processing and divides on row processing.
Here's a simple example that handles uuid types from some code I have:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, CHAR
import uuid


class GUID(TypeDecorator):
# Also see:
# http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type

impl = CHAR

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        else:
            if not isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
                 return uuid.UUID(value).hex
            else:
                return value.hex

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        else:
            return uuid.UUID(value)
```

Having impl set to char is wrong for everything besides sqlite, because that won't set the length of the column that gets declared.
This should give you a good idea how to put together the price type.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. thanks so much!