# Marshmallow validation incorrectly fails when using an SQLAlchemy TypeDecorator

Tags: python, validation, sqlalchemy, uuid, marshmallow

I have created a TypeDecorator based off of the [SQLAlchemy example](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/custom_types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type) that converts between a 32-character hex string and the `BINARY` database column in which the UUID is stored:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import uuid
from sqlalchemy import types, func

#https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/custom_types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type
class HashColumn(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl=types.BINARY

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            return uuid.UUID(hex=value).bytes

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return uuid.UUID(bytes=value).hex


    def copy(self, **kw):
        return HashColumn(self.impl.length)
```

**Model:**

```
def get_uuid():
    return uuid.uuid4().hex

class School(db.Model):
    """
        description: A School
    """
    __tablename__ = "schools"
    id = db.Column('school_id', HashColumn(length=16), primary_key=True, default=get_uuid)
    ...
```

However, the problem I am having is that my marshmallow schemas, which are being generated from the SQLAlchemy Models, aren't seeing this column as a 32-character string:

**Schema:**

```
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema
...
class SchoolSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = School
        include_relationships = True
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = True
...
```

**in my code:**

```
try:
    new_object = SchoolSchema().load(data, session=db.session)
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.messages)
    print(err.valid_data)
```

when running this code on with a perfectly-valid UUID of `a5fad20c691546ae8871390d980aae6d`, marshmallow throws a validation error and gives the following output:

```
{"id": ["Longer than maximum length 16."]}
```

Since I would like to have the UUID's formated as 32-character hex strings (or python UUID's where applicable) during use, and converted to `BINARY(16)` right before storing in the database, I need to get rid of this validation error, but I am unsure of how to do that because changing the length parameter on the SQLAlchemy model will mean that the database tables will be created as `BINARY(32)` instead of `BINARY(16)`, doubling the length.

**Is it possible to set up a SQLAlchemy `TypeDecorator` so that it stores a type of one length (`BINARY(16)`) in the Database, but presents a different length (`CHAR(32)`) to Python and/orSQLAlchemy so that marshmallow can correctly validate the length as a 32-character string?**

I have already looked on StackOverflow for other questions like this one:

- [SQLAlchemy: How to represent data in Python differently than in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671034/sqlalchemy-how-to-represent-data-in-python-differently-than-in-the-database/43700661?r=SearchResults&s=3|28.1931#43700661)

but this seems to be about converting the type itself, which I have already done in my sample code. I cannot seem to find any that mention how to convert the *length* of a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have found two ways to solve this issue:

1. adjust the types of the TypeDecorator so that it acts like a `CHAR` column instead of a binary column and use `load_dialect_impl` to change the type as presented to the database, specifying the different length as a parameter

   ```
   class HashColumn(types.TypeDecorator):
       impl=types.CHAR

       def load_dialect_impl(self, dialect):
           return dialect.type_descriptor(types.BINARY(16))

      ...
   ```

   (the rest of the class is basically the same as in the question)

   This change allowed me to change the `HashColumn(length=16)` definition from my DB models to `HashColumn(length=32)`, allowing marshmallow to correctly interpret the length.
2. Alternatively, I could change my implementation of my API PATCH/update endpoints to fetch and update the existing object from the database, rather than creating a completely new object and trying to merge their values. This completely removes the Marshmallow validation since the ID is no longer being used to create a new object, however, to me this felt like too much of a workaround and meant that, because marshmallow validation was not being used, it would also not validate any of the other data fields.